# Is it discrimination that women live longer but don't pay higher pension contributions?

Tags: discrimination, gender, pensions

In UK women live 4 years longer on average than men(79 vs 83). However, national insurance is the same for both genders. The similar situation exists in most countries(in many countries it is even worse since women retire much earlier). Why is it not considered the gender discrimination and never discussed in media (like gender pay gap)?

Comment: So fat people and smokers should pay less contributions?

Comment: They don't because the healthcare expenses on them are also higher. At the same time - men do not require higher healthcare expenses than women.

Comment: @DraifKroneg Actually, men **do** require more healthcare expenses. [Statistically, men are much more susceptible to various conditions which require expensive treatment](https://www.health.harvard.edu/newsletter_article/mars-vs-venus-the-gender-gap-in-health). But this is overall a discussion-oriented topic, and Q&A websites are not an appropriate medium to have discussions.

Comment: The Court of Justice of the European Union is of the opposite opinion, i.e. that different contributions or different payouts are discriminatory: [Case C‑236/09](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=80019&pageIndex=0&doclang=EN&mode=req&dir=&occ=first&part=1). In general, it boils down to the question *why* women live longer – is it a biological principle, or is it due to different life styles? It seems that question is still unresolved.

Comment: In a defined-contributions pension plan, women and men contribute equally, but insurance companies offer smaller annuities to the statistically longer-lived women upon retirement

Comment: @DJohnM: That's irrelevant - it's because they get paid less during their work life due to the gender pay gap.

Comment: @Philipp: It’s actually true that, over their whole lives, men cause *less* healthcare costs in comparison to women. For that reason, private health insurance in Germany used to be more expensive for women up to the court opinion that I mentioned above (and that despite pregnancy costs already being shared equally between the sexes in the calculation).

Comment: Not all readers here are from the UK.  Please provide a link which describes those parts of the UK's pension system most relevant to this question.

Comment: "Put on hold as primarily opinion-based . . ." That is absurd. If you are going to have Stack Exchange Politics, you should allow opinion based questions.

Comment: I think this is the very definition of *the opposite of* discrimination.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch - I think the distinction on this stack exchange is when you cross the line into, pretty much, *exclusively* opinion-based

Comment: The opinion of "What crosses the line and what does not" is ALSO an opinion!

Comment: This is perhaps a better fit for [philosophy SX](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @WilliamJockusch There is plenty of (mostly) political questions that can be objectively answered. Lining out typical answers based on main political ideologies also isn't opinion based. Btw. I'm not saying this is or is not a primarily opinion based question (for me it would be on the fence), but claiming that there is nothing left if you exclude primarily opinion based questions is absurd.